# I have binary images of playing card values and want to convert them to integers using pytesseract

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, ocr, tesseract

I have several images of the value character displayed on a playing card as shown above (for example i use these 9 images). I want to convert them using image recognition to the correct integer value on the playing card (normally 1 to 13 for ace to king).

[image: 9 Binary images of playing card values]

I have tried using the tesseract library, but its its giving me wrong results:

```
extracted_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(number_isolated, config='--psm 6')
    
    
def extract_rank(text):
    # Implement your logic to extract the rank here
    # You may need regular expressions or a custom parsing function
    # Example: '2 of Hearts' -> '2'
        return text.split()[0]
    print('extr text :',extracted_text)
    rank = extract_rank(extracted_text)

# Map rank to card value (modify this according to your card game's rules)
    card_value = card_values.get(rank, 0)
    return card_value

card_values = {
        '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6,
        '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9, '10': 10,
        'J': 11, 'Q': 12, 'K': 13, 'A': 1
    }
```

Results:

```
extr text : Y
extr text : 5
extr text : Ly
extr text : 1Q
extr text : A
extr text : i<
extr text : 4
extr text : 65
extr text : 5
```

We can see that there is a result, for example for the K it gives me i< which makes sense, but it is clearly not a perfect result. I would like to make it perfect, is there anyone here who can help me?
I made sure the images are binary with preprocessing, and they are cropped to the first pixel that has the value 1 (as viewed from above, from the left, right and bottom). If unclear, feel free to ask!

i tried to just apply the tesseract command but it gives me very bad results:

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(number_isolated, config='--psm 6')
```

Additional info:

I tried to update the command to the follwoing:

```
extracted_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(number_isolated, config='--psm 10 tessedit_char_whitelist=A2345678910JQK')
```

i tried to whitelist the 13 characters on playing cards and i added psm10 for single character detection only (however i just realised that might give problems with the 10)

Comment: You might get on better with *"template matching"* than with OCR, especially if your font is fixed.

Comment: The MNIST dataset contains handwritten digits and serves the same purpose. You can use [KNN](https://www.kaggle.com/code/maharshipandya/mnist-using-knn-97) and a custom [CNN Model](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-convolutional-neural-network-from-scratch-for-mnist-handwritten-digit-classification/), they may produce better results.

Comment: the images are not identical. there are some variations in the shapes of identical numbers. @ mark setchell